# Radio button checked

Tags: javascript, html, asp-classic

When submitting my form the radio buttons do not give "checked" when they are checked. The form works well otherwise but I can't get a value from the buttons. Any suggestions on the current code?

```
<form action="" method="post" id="termCloudForm">
    <nobr>
        Slot: 
        <input type="text" name="Slot" size="6" 
          <% If Request.Form("Slot") <> "" Then Response.Write(" value=""" & Request.Form("Slot") & """") %> 
         />
    </nobr>
    <nobr>
        Date: 
        <input type="text" name="Date" size="6" 
          <% If Request.Form("Date") <> "" Then Response.Write(" value=""" & Request.Form("Date") & """") %> 
        />
    </nobr>
    <nobr>
        <input type="radio" id="radio_button_1" name="radio_button" value="1" /> 
        rad1     
    </nobr>
    <nobr>
        <input type="radio" id="radio_button_2" name="radio_button" value="2" /> 
        rad2 
    </nobr>
<input type="submit" name="action" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

and the javascript part where I retrieve it has been simplified considerably to just check if it has been coming through. I think forcing it into javascript for the termcloud is where I'm getting errors, but I'm not sure where.

```
function initTermCloud() {
var myForm = document.getElementById("termCloudForm");
var slot = myForm.elements["Slot"].value;
var date = myForm.elements["Date"].value;
var url = encodeURI('http://TermCloudJSON2Local.asp?Slot=' + slot + '&Date=' + date);

alert(myForm.elements["radio_button_1"].checked == true);
var query = new google.visualization.Query(url);
query.setTimeout(20);
query.send(queryResponse);
}
```

Comment: Have you tried outputting the whole POST array to make sure you're not just missing the value?

Comment: Can you show the code where you try to retrieve your values?

Answer (score 1):

using

```
<% response.write(request.form("radio_button")) %>
```

must print 1 or 2 depending on your selection.

this doesn't works ?

edit: based on your edited question

try this

```
function validate(){
    var cont=0;
    var result=false;
    var oArr=document.getElementsByName('radio_button');
    for(cont=0;cont < oArr.length;cont++){
        if(oArr[cont].checked == true){
            alert(oArr[cont].id + 'was checked');
            result=true;
        }
    }
    return(result);
}
```

Comment: So the <% response.write(request.form("radio_button")) %> comes out correctly but it doesn't seem to pass correctly to the javascript part of the code and I don't know why.

Comment: your approach to check which radio buton is cheked is wrong, radio buttons/ check boxes behave as array of elements based on their name, the correct approach is getting the whole array and the iterate between them and check for checked state

Comment: So I have just tried your code but it doesn't alert. I think the problem could be in that the form action is itself and hence it picks up the unchecked buttons. Not sure how to change this though.

Comment: I still can't get it to work but thanks for the help it's been really useful so far

Answer (score 1):

Try find with ID as below.

```
function initTermCloud() {
        var myForm = document.getElementById("termCloudForm");
        var slot = myForm.elements["Slot"].value;
        var date = myForm.elements["Date"].value;
        var url = encodeURI('http://TermCloudJSON2Local.asp?Slot=' + slot + '&Date=' + date);

        alert(document.getElementById("radio_button_1").checked)

        var query = new google.visualization.Query(url);
        query.setTimeout(20);
        query.send(queryResponse);
    }
```

Comment: I initially used this exact code but I only get the initial value of the radio buttons i.e. unchecked or if I set one to checked initially then that comes out. I think it may be to do with posting to itself. Not sure why though.

Answer (score 1):

Since Rafael gave you the correct ASP syntax to retrieve the radio button value (i.e. his Response.Write code) you don't need that.

If you're having problems with initTermCloud, you can use the answer Jinesh jain gave you.  Alternatively, you could do something like this:

http://www.randomsnippets.com/2008/05/15/how-to-loop-through-checkboxes-or-radio-button-groups-via-javascript/